# Wrong reading of text file in c++

Tags: c++, text-files

I just want to read a text file and store the data into a vector. Thereby the value weight should be sum till the limit is reached. The first four lines will be read correctly but the following will not read. What is the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

/*
Data.txt 

John
6543
23

Max
342
2

A Team
5645
23
*/

struct entry
{
    // passengers data
    std::string name;
    int weight; // kg
    std::string group_code; 
};

void reservations()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.clear();
    file.open("reservations.txt");
    file.close();
}

entry read_passenger(std::ifstream &stream_in)
{
    entry passenger;
    if (stream_in)
    {
        std::getline(stream_in, passenger.name); 
        stream_in >> passenger.weight;
        std::getline(stream_in, passenger.group_code);
        stream_in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        return passenger;
    }

    return passenger; 
}

int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream stream_in("data.txt"); 
    std::vector<entry> v; // contains the passengers data
    const int limit_total_weight = 10000;   // kg
    int total_weight = 0;                   // kg
    entry current;
    while (!stream_in.eof())
    {
        current = read_passenger(stream_in);
        total_weight = total_weight + current.weight;
        std::cout << current.name << std::endl;
        if (total_weight >= limit_total_weight)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines,

```
    std::getline(stream_in, passenger.group_code);
    stream_in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

should be in the opposite order:

```
    stream_in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::getline(stream_in, passenger.group_code);
```

Think about what the *purpose* of the `ignore` is.

Also, instead of checking only for EOF, check for general error.

I.e., instead of

```
    while (!stream_in.eof())
```

write

```
    while (stream_in)
```

Maybe there's more wrong, but the above is what I saw immediately.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: What you say is almost correct, but you need to place the ignore also after the "passenger.groupcode" to skip the newline separating the entries.

Comment: oh there are blank lines. right then, ignore is one way to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

I try not to mix formatted and line-oriented input for precisely this reason. If it were me, and I had to use `getline` anywhere, I would use `getline` everywhere:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

struct entry
{
    // passengers data
    std::string name;
    int weight; // kg
    std::string group_code;
};

void reservations()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.clear();
    file.open("reservations.txt");
    file.close();
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream_in, entry& passenger)
{
    std::getline(stream_in, passenger.name);

    std::string weightString;
    std::getline(stream_in, weightString);
    std::istringstream (weightString) >> passenger.weight;

    std::getline(stream_in, passenger.group_code);

    return stream_in;
}

void read_blankline(std::istream& stream_in) {
    std::string blank;
    std::getline(stream_in, blank);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream stream_in("data.txt");
    std::vector<entry> v; // contains the passengers data
    const int limit_total_weight = 10000;   // kg
    int total_weight = 0;                   // kg
    entry current;
    while (stream_in >> current)
    {
        total_weight = total_weight + current.weight;
        std::cout << current.name << std::endl;
        if (total_weight >= limit_total_weight)
        {
            break;
        }
        read_blankline(stream_in);
    }
    return 0;
}
```